# Geometry nodes - How to select last point on many different curves

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have a bunch of curves, none of which have the same amount of points. It's a curve line that's been instanced on points and then realized, deformed and finally resampled. I'd like to select the very last point on all of them, by comparing their index with -1. I'm using the index given by the *spline parameter* node, which is supposed to be per-curve. However -1 doesn't seem to work, the selection is empty. I tried approaching the problem by capturing/storing a boolean attribute on the last point at curve creation, but the attribute propagation makes the boolean true on several points. Same happens if I try storing an integer : half the points inherit 0, the other half inherit 1.

The only way this works is by comparing the *spline parameter factor* with 1, but that seems convoluted and needlessly costly. Am I missing something ?

Cheers !

Comment: [Endpoint Selection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/endpoint_selection.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @quellenform has commented, *Endpoint Selection* is probably the cleanest way to go. Here, the attribute is captured on realized and deformed curve instances, so it survives conversion to points:

[image]

[image]